# Laravel 5 : JSON responce contains a special character

Tags: json, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5 and I'm trying to create a JSON object in my controller like this:

```
public function sendPost() {
  $id = 5;
  return response()->json($id);
}
```

This gives me a response of:

```
"↵""5"
```

Why is there a special character in the key?

Answer (score 0):

There is no valid json response that returns a single id. You will need a key value pair or you return it as array

Example Key Value

```
return array("id" => $id)
```

Example Array

```
return array($id);
```

if you need to be specific about json ( should be automatically )

```
return response()->json(array($id));
```

Or

```
return response()->json(array("id"=>$id));
```

Comment: Its working fine in laravel So I think issue is somewhere else

Comment: what is working finein laravel? you can ofcourse return a json but it will always result in this special char stuff if you do not provide an array. What is you desired result? Why do you return json if you actually want to return plain text? { "5" } is not valid json, neither is { 5 } nor "5" itself (https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Comment: Just return your id plain ( return $id ) you will see that laravel will not parse this into json for a good reason